# How to get field of filtered value in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to get item in list with filter and then get its field, like this:

```
{% if (trees|lookup:subtree_num).task_count %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way, try this:

```
{%for data in trees %}

    {% if forloop.counter == subtree_num %}
        {{ data.task_count }}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```